Broadcast Receiver Intent set from within a Service not being received by other Service
I'm pretty new at kotlin.
I'm trying to know if an application is in the foreground or background, in order to know if to play a custom sound for a notification or not.
I got this piece of code to notify the other service if it's in the background or not:
`
package com.blah.modules.observer
....

class BackgroundForegroundListener(private val context: Context) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onCreate(owner)
    Timber.i("onCreate ")

}

override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onStart(owner)
    Timber.i("onStart ")
    sendForegroundState(true)
}

override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onStop(owner)
    Timber.i("onStop ")
    sendForegroundState(false)
}

override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onResume(owner)
    Timber.i("onResume ")
    sendForegroundState(true)
}

override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onDestroy(owner)
    Timber.i("onDestroy ")
}

override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onPause(owner)
    Timber.i("onPause ")
    sendForegroundState(false)
}

private fun sendForegroundState(isForeground: Boolean) {
    Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_UPDATE_FOREGROUND_STATE").also { intent ->
        intent.putExtra("foreground", isForeground)
        context.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}

}
And this other piece of code:
package com.blah.modules.notification
...
class FirebasePushNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

lateinit var accountRepository: AccountRepository
lateinit var pushHandler: PushHandler
lateinit var prefsStorage: PrefsStorage
var foreground: Boolean = false

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ...
    pushHandler = PushHandler(baseContext, prefsStorage)
    val filter = IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_UPDATE_FOREGROUND_STATE")
    registerReceiver(foregroundReceiver, filter)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(foregroundReceiver)
}

...

private val foregroundReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val isForeground = intent?.getBooleanExtra("foreground", false) ?: false
        foreground = isForeground
        Timber.d("Foreground state updated: $foreground")
    }
}
}`

It seems to be sent from the first class, but not the second.
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT
For anyone who, in the future, regards this problem with perplexity, here is the solution implemented in a service:
private fun isAppInForeground(): Boolean {
    val lifecycle = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle
    return lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
}


Implicit Intents largely have been banned for several years. If all this code is in a single app process, you do not need to use a broadcast. Otherwise, you need to use an explicit Intent, such as by calling setPackage() on it to identify the application ID of the intended recipient.

@CommonsWare Yes, it's in a single application. How would I set the value of the "foreground" boolean from within the FirebasePushNotificationService  from the BackgroundForegroundListener? Should I use a regular setter? But applied to which specific object, since it's not a singleton, or a bean (as it is in Spring - Boot)

@BaconSky You can always bind to a service to get an API object for it.  But I'm questioning why you want to do this in the first place-  needing to know if your app is in the foreground when you get an FCM message is unusual at a minimum, and I wonder if there isn't a better way to do it.

Beyond Gabe's good points, FirebasePushNotificationService can find out for itself the lifecycle status of the UI, using ProcessLifecycleOwner.

@GabeSechan Well, I need to change the sound of a notification whenever it's in the background, for notifications coming from the FirebaseMessagingService, and in order to do that I firstly need to have the knowledge if the app is in the background or foreground

@CommonsWare Is there anywhere I could get a basic example of this? Much appreciated :D I checked online, yet failed to find it :(

See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle and https://medium.com/@santimattius/detect-when-our-app-is-sent-to-the-foreground-or-background-on-android-how-can-you-effectively-fb9e539796ea

For anyone who, in the future, regards this problem with perplexity, here is the solution implemented in a service:
private fun isAppInForeground(): Boolean {
    val lifecycle = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle
    return lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
}

